# How to save a fbprophet forecast model using pickle such that the model takes user input when loaded

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, pickle, facebook-prophet

I have built an fbProphet model which contains date and items as columns. There are 50 such item columns. I need to save this model in pickle format. Each time I load the model, it should take 'item_number' as user input, then predict the future dates. How to save the model such that it takes user input when loaded. Below is the code of model fitting.

```
def model_fit(item_number):
  #Calling the dataframe for specific item
  item_data = data(item_number) #Function call - data(item_number)
  train, test = item_data[item_data['ds'] <= '2016-12-31'], item_data[item_data['ds'] > '2016-12-31']
  model = Prophet(interval_width = 0.80, changepoint_range = 0.9)
  #model = Prophet(changepoint_range=0.9)
  model.fit(train)

  return model
```

In the above code, when I run, `model = model_fit(item_number)`, it fits the model of training data for that particular item. If I save this into pickle, it saves the model fitted for that item_number alone. How to save the model such that when the model is loaded, the 'item_number' is taken as input.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to save fitted Prophet models so that they can be loaded and used later.

In Python, models should not be saved with pickle; the Stan backend attached to the model object will not pickle well, and will produce issues under certain versions of Python. Instead, you should use the built-in serialization functions to serialize the model to json:

```
# Python
from prophet.serialize import model_to_json, model_from_json

with open('serialized_model.json', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(model_to_json(m))  # Save model

with open('serialized_model.json', 'r') as fin:
    m = model_from_json(fin.read())  # Load model
```

Source: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/additional_topics.html